# I designed an html page but my href and my youtube iframe isn't letting me click

Tags: html, css, youtube, click, href

I have a web page with just one CSS file and one html file and I don't know why I can't click on this YouTube embedded link or click on "click here" a.href

https://codepen.io/deuelJordan/pen/XWgQGJK

```
        <iframe width="750" height="422" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rt-2cxAiPJk"
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
```

thank a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the z-index documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

You should change the

```
z-index: -1;
```

to

```
z-index: 1;
```

this will make the code link you want others to access work.

If there is anything else I can help with it, it'll be my pleasure to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your CSS part.
if you change

```
z-index: -1;
```

to

```
z-index: 1;
```

your page will be working

Answer (score 0):

Just comment or remove `z-index` as below:

```
.black-rect {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* z-index: -1; */
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
    position: relative;
    left: 125px;
}
```

You can check the updated demo on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/tibichi/pen/NWgmVOE